# HTML elements move when page is refreshed or link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website for my friend and for some reason that I can not figure out the styling gets all messed up when you refresh the site multiple times quickly or when you open a link. I have included before and after images so you can see what I mean. I've been trying to search the internet for answers to why this is happening but I can not find anything so if anyone can take a look at my code and tell me what is wrong it would be much appreciated.

```js
function openDistance() {
        var div = document.getElementById("distance-popup");
        div.style.display = "block";
    }
    function closeDistance() {
        var div = document.getElementById("distance-popup");
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    scrollbar-color: #070600 #5C6672;
}
body {
    background-image: url(./images/BAKER\ background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.top {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}


.bigtitle {
    text-align: center;
    color: #A52A2A;
    font-size: 16.1vw;
}

.nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 30vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 100vh;
}

#releases {
    left: 30%;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
  
#about  {
    left: 80%;
    top: 20%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}
  
#meet {
    left: 30%;
    top: 40%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}
  
#socials {
    left: 80%;
    top: 60%;
    margin-left: -70px;
}
  

.nav a {
    font-size: 3vw;
    transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in-out;
    color: #A52A2A;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%; /* Adjust the horizontal position */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin-left: -50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 7.5vh; /* Fixed height for the links */
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevents content from overflowing */
}

.nav a:hover {
    font-size: 3.3vw;
}

.aboutme {
    position: relative;
    top: 20vh;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 110vh;
    background-color: #070600;
    background-size: cover;
  }



.aboutme p {
    color: #F4F2F2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.blank{
    position: relative;
    top: 20vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    top: 20vh;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 100vw;
    height: 110vh;
    background:rgba(7, 6, 0, 0.95);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.carousel{
    max-width: 60vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel_items{
    display: inline-block;
    animation: carousel 8s linear infinite;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.carousel_img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 50vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 10px;
}

@keyframes carousel {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
}

.carousel_img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.title{
    color: #a52a2a;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    user-select: none;
}

.popup .title{
    color: #a52a2a;
    font-size: 3vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    user-select: none;
    z-index: 3;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 55%;
    height: 95%;
    background-color: #070600;

    z-index: 2;
}

.popup img{
    width: 50vh;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
.links{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50vh;
    height: 6vh;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.links a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.links a img{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 5vh;
}
.links a img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
.x-button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #5C6672;
    color: #F4F2F2;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .x-button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  
  .x-button:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="baker.css">
    <title>BAKER!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top">
        <p class="bigtitle">BAKER!</p>
    </div>
    

    <div class="nav"> 
        <a id="releases" href="#newreleases_title">My Projects!</a>
        <a id="about" href="#aboutme_title">About Me!</a>
        <a id="meet" href="#meetthecrew_title">The Kitchen Crew!</a>
        <a id="socials" href="#socials_title">My Socials!</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title" id="newreleases_title">My Projects!</h1>

        <div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel_items">
                <img src="images/distance.JPEG" class="carousel_img" onclick="openDistance()">
                <img src="images/Mi amor.jpeg" class="carousel_img">
                <img src="images/overandupcover.jpg" class="carousel_img">
                <!--REPEAT IMAGES-->
                <img src="images/distance.JPEG" class="carousel_img" onclick="openDistance()">
                <img src="images/Mi amor.jpeg" class="carousel_img">
                <img src="images/overandupcover.jpg" class="carousel_img">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popup" id="distance-popup">
        <button class="x-button" onclick="closeDistance()">X</button>
        <h1 class="title">Distance</h1>
        <img class="image" src="./images/distance.JPEG">
        <div class="links">
            <a href="https://open.spotify.com/track/1MiaGK2uKor5ZyKiu0CFEv?si=c264150192034dbd" target="_blank"><img class="logo" src="./images/spotify.png"></a>
            <a href=""target="_blank"><img class="logo" src="./images/applemusic.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="blank"></div>

    <div class="content"> 
        <h1 class="title" id="aboutme_title">About Me!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="blank"></div>

    <div class="content"> 
        <h1 class="title" id="meetthecrew_title">The Kitchen Crew!</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="blank"></div>

    <div class="content"> 
        <h1 class="title" id="socials_title">My Socials!</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I was not sure how to add in the images if that is even an option in this editor. I am also using the latest version of Google Chrome to test the site.

**Intended look before refreshing or leaving the site:**

[image]

**Messed up look after refreshing or leaving the site:**

[image]

Comment: This might be a caching problem with the page if you have just written the code and the browser has not updated the cached page yet. Besides, I see no difference on here.

Comment: Please clear the browser cache manually.

Comment: As previous comments said, it seems to be a browser's cache issue. You can solve it, in a permanent way, attaching a query string to the CSS file name set in the `<link>` *href* property with a value which always change on every load/refresh; e.g. a timestamp. Doing this, browser will always load an updated CSS file, avoiding user's issue with browser's cache.